# Can I un-insulate my basement quickly, and refinish it slowly over time?

Tags: basement, vapor-barrier, basement-refinishing, basement-insulation

I live in MN, so, a very northern climate. The previous owners of my home insulated the belowground basement poorly. It is air conditioned and heated, but insulated with 2in fiberglass bats and wood right up against the concrete and a vapor barrier over them. As you can imagine, we have a condensation and mold problem now.

I know what I have to do to fix it - check and fix water issues, stick some EPS boards up, tape the joints, etc. - but I don't know when I should rip out the old insulation. Can I do it all at once and just let the walls sit and breathe/dry as I slowly put up the new materials? Or am I losing out on a lot of energy and should only remove parts that I am able to replace in a reasonable amount of time? We've done diy projects before, but slowly and it's a pretty big space, about 50ft of wall area.

Comment: Underground you do not have as much heat lost/gain as above ground, so energy lost is not as much.

Comment: MN isn't a very northern climate.   Maybe if you are at the canadian border it is kind of northern.    How much of your basement is below and above grade?

Comment: I guess I don't know what's considered northern, we're just north of the twin cities, plant zone 4a, so I guess that's not bad compared to Canada for sure. The basement has an 8ft ceiling, at least 6 of the 8 are below grade, and it's a split level so one wall touches the inside of the house.

Comment: As a Canadian we have to go further north to get to 4a.  I will take my 6a any day.